# Fixing a misaligned door lock

Tags: lock

I have a typical lock in an exterior door as shown. Note that this door also has a deadbolt, so this is perhaps not a critical fix, but I still would prefer this non-deadbolt to be working properly.

[image]

The strike plate (1) is misaligned with the bolt (2) so the bolt does not go into the opening in the strike plate (the strike plate is almost 1/16" too high).

I am wondering how to fix this to maintain the most strength/integrity of the lock. Would it be one of these, or something else...?

(a) file the opening in the metal strike plate enough so that the bolt fits? Here is a closeup of the strike plate -- I do not think it leaves enough room for such a maneuver...

[image]

(b) move the strike plate down on the frame. Opposite problem here -- it would need too small a movement for the new holes in the wood to be separate from the old holes. Or would it be OK to set the new screw holes at an angle...?

Comment: Are the hinges worn? That would cause lock misalignment...

Comment: I think Mike is right - assuming that this latch used to be aligned in the past. You should try to fix the cause, not the symptoms.

Comment: My go-to quick fix is to put a 3" long screw into the top hinge. In 90% of cases, that pulls the door back into its original alignment.

Comment: First figure out why there is the misalignment.

Comment: Check the hinge screws are any loose? Has the door frame shifted, from the picture I get the impression it has. If something has been hung on the door it would also cause that problem.

Comment: Good suggestion about hinges, folks. Alas, no problem there: I examined the hinges carefully looking for clues but they are in pristine shape, and the door is not sagging at all. Now I do not see any evidence, but I suppose it is possible the frame itself has shifted, because this is a rather old house (though the door and frame were new about 10 years ago or so).